# Get localized app title from .ipa file downloaded in desktop iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I am trying to find the localized app title from an ipa file, downloaded in iTunes on a Mac. The path to the ipas are likely:

```
/Users/yourname/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/*.ipa
```

I've successfully managed to get localized icon titles (short, displayed below icon), but not the (longer) official titles for an app.

Maybe the plain answer is, the localized titles aren't in the ipa? I don't recall coding the full app titles into the app itself really, only the icon titles. App titles are only available "online", at iTunes servers.

Comment: Are you looking for the localized name that appears under the icon? Those are in the InfoPlist.strings files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has an API exactly for these kinds of metadata:
https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Your query URL will look like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<your app's iTunes ID>&country=<country code>
```

Comment: Yes, I know about that one. I was trying to find the info inside the .ipa, a lot of data is already in there.

Comment: But the official titles are set in iTunes Connect, not in the XCode project. So you won't find them in the ipa file unless you explicitly defined them somewhere.